# Active Directory security groups Search application optimization

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, active-directory

I have a Web API method that returns the  Active Directory security groups for the specific login user. The below code was working fine but it was taking so munch time nearly 45 sec to get the results.

```
DirectoryEntry root = GetDirectoryEntry()
  using (var groups = root.Children.Find("OU=Sample Security Groups"))
                        {
                            using (var directory = groups.Children.Find("OU=Permissions"))
                            {
                                using (var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(directory))
                                {
                                    searcher.Filter = `filter condition`
                                    var results = searcher.FindAll();
                                    foreach (SearchResult result in results)
                                    {
                                        if (result != null)
                                        {
                                            using (DirectoryEntry group = result.GetDirectoryEntry())
                                            {
                                                items.Add((string)group.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

Update:  In the `GetDirectoryEntry` method we are creating the connection to the active directory using the username and password.

Can anyone help to optimize the code using `Parallel.ForEach` or threading etc..

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! To get better answers you should add some more code, e.g the whole method and the `GetDirectoryEntry()` method as well.

Answer (score 1):

Let us first review the code.

- Stacking `using`s will reduce the level of indentation.
- The `Filter` of the `DirectorySearcher` can be passed to the constructor
- If the expected result of the `FindAll()` call will be huge, you should consider to return only needed properties, by using this [overloaded constructor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_DirectoryServices_DirectorySearcher__ctor_System_DirectoryServices_DirectoryEntry_System_String_System_String___) of the `DirectorySearcher` class.
- The `SearchResultCollection` returned by `DirectorySearcher.FindAll()` implements the `IDisposable` interface hence it should be enclosed in a `using` as well. The [remarks section](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.findall?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) of the documentation states:

  > Due to implementation restrictions, the SearchResultCollection class
  >   cannot release all of its unmanaged resources when it is garbage
  >   collected. To prevent a memory leak, you must call the Dispose method
  >   when the SearchResultCollection object is no longer needed.

Implementing some of this changes could look like so

```
DirectoryEntry root = GetDirectoryEntry();
using (var groups = root.Children.Find("OU=Sample Security Groups"))
using (var directory = groups.Children.Find("OU=Permissions"))
using (var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(directory, "filter condition"))
using (var results = searcher.FindAll())
{
    foreach (SearchResult result in results)
    {
        if (result != null)
        {
            using (var group = result.GetDirectoryEntry())
            {
                items.Add((string)group.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

If you only need to get the `SamAccountName`'s of the groups a specific user is a member of you can use `UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity()` like so

```
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domain", "username", "password"), IdentityType.SamAccountName, "loginUser");

foreach (GroupPrincipal group in user.GetGroups())
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine(group.SamAccountName);
}
```